# Is there a name for this piecewise cubic interpolation kernel

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

I went looking for a way to do piecewise cubic interpolation, like natural cubic splines, but:

- expressible as a convolution of data points with a piecewise cubic kernel; and
- still C2-continuous
- still passes through all the data points
- still cubic between integer abscissas
- kernel converges to $0$ at $\pm\infty$

I did the math and figured out there's only one solution -- the kernel is a piecewise cubic function, characterized as follows:

\begin{split}
 y(0) &= 1\\
 y(x) &= 0,\text{ for all integer }x \neq 0\\
 y'(x) &= sgn(x) * 3(\sqrt3-2)^{|x|},\text{ for all integer }x\\
\end{split}
which implies

$$y''(x) = -6\sqrt 3(\sqrt3-2)^{|x|},\text{ for all integer }x \neq 0$$

This turns out to make a pretty nice interpolation, without a lot of ringing or arbitrary boundary conditions, so...  what's it actually called?

EDIT:  It's been a while, and still no takers.  In the interim, I made a demo.  See: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/mtimmerm/IPythonNotebooks/blob/master/NaturalCubicSplines.ipynb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of comments (that are too long for a comment).

Firstly, your splines have uniform knot spacing. So, the matrix in the usual system of linear equations is fixed, and you can invert it symbolically, once and for all. Having done this, you have a simple formula that gives you the interpolating spline as a function of the data points.

I don't know anything about convolution kernels, but the functions you're using look a lot like so-called "cardinal" splines. Again, using uniform knots located at the integers, the $i$-th cardinal spline $s_i$ satisfies $s_i(i) = 1$ and $s_i(j)=0$ for $j \ne i$. Then, the spline $s$ defined by
$$
s(x) = \sum a_i s_i(x)
$$
interpolates the $a_i$ values. Specifically $s(i)=a_i$ for all $i$.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but these are not the same.  Cardinal splines only join with continuous first (not second) derivatives.  Joining cubic splines with C2 continuity adds a lot more constraints, and makes every segment dependent on every point.  So if you invert the usual tridiagonal matrix for C2 cubic splines, the result is not sparse and only works for a specific number of knots.  (EDIT: I looked up cardinal spline and it doesn't look like what you wrote...  I'll do a more extensive search)

Comment: You might be thinking of the Lagrange polynomials, which are usually explained that way, IIRC, but those are not splines

Comment: I'm not thinking of Lagrange polynomials. The terminology is a mess -- different people mean different things by "cardinal spline". But, whatever you call them, it's clear that there are C2 splines $s_i$ with the property that $s_i(j) = \delta_{ij}$. Lagrange polynomials have this same property, but, as you say, they are different things.

Comment: The inverted matrix is not sparse, but the entries near the diagonal will be larger than the ones farther away, and this is what produces the "decay" property.

Comment: I was able to find the work you were talking about.  The term "cardinal spline interpolation" is used generically by Schoenberg to mean spline interpolation with integer knot points.  He does indeed develop essentially the same formula in, for example, here: http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183533186

Comment: Yes, that's it. I should have said that I meant "cardinal spline" in the sense of Schoenberg.